# Secure LDAP PHP Script?

Tags: php, security, ldap, session-variables

I want to know if my scripts are secure. Especially storing the serialized object in a session variable.

index.php is a Login for a protected Site (I left out the html part). The protected Site reads and prints Infos from LDAP. In order to read LDAP Infos from a user entry, the user have to be bind with LDAP otherwise ldap_read returns an error. Without an user bind in main.php was my faulty first attempt.

Another possibility is to include main.php in index.php if the login is successful. But i don't want to do it this way.

So I tried it this way and it works but I'm not sure how secure this is. Especially the object in the session variable.

```
# index.php
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once("LDAP.php");
    if (isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['loginName']) && isset($_POST['loginPassword'])){        
        $ActiveDirectoryUser = new ActiveDirectoryUser($_POST['loginName'], $_POST['loginPassword']);
        if ($ActiveDirectoryUser->connect()) {                
            $_SESSION['unique_string'] = true;
            $_SESSION['unique_string_Obj'] = serialize($ActiveDirectoryUser);
            header('Location: main.php');
        }
    }
?>
```

```
# LDAP.php
<?php
/**
 * Always have documentation here
 */
class ActiveDirectoryUser {
    private $connection;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $ldap_db = "Server Adress";
    private $ldap_connection;

    /**
     * Always have documentation 
     * @param $username string
     * @param $password string
     */
    public function __construct($username, $password) {
      $this->username = "uid=".$username.",ou=users,dc="company_name",dc=de";
      $this->password = $password;
    }

    /**
     * Always have documentation
     */
    public function __destruct(){
        ldap_close($this->ldap_connection);
    }

    /**
     * Always have documentation 
     * @param $username string
     * @param $password string
     */

    public function connect() {
        $this->ldap_connection = ldap_connect($this->ldap_db);

        if ($bind = ldap_bind($this->ldap_connection, $this->username, $this->password)) {
            return True;
        } else {
            return False;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Always have documentation
     */
    public function getInfos(){
        ldap_set_option($this->ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
        ldap_set_option($this->ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

        $bind = ldap_bind($this->ldap_connection, $this->username, $this->password);

        $filter = "(objectclass=*)";

        $justthese = array("sn", "givenname", "mail");

        $sr = ldap_read($this->ldap_connection, $this->username, $filter, $justthese);

        $info = ldap_get_entries($this->ldap_connection, $sr);

        return $info;
    }
}
?>
```

```
# main.php
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once("LDAP.php");
    $ActiveDirectoryUser = unserialize($_SESSION["unique_string_Obj"]);            
    if($ActiveDirectoryUser->connect()) {                
        $entry = $ActiveDirectoryUser->getInfos();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do I see it right that you are storing the serialized User-Object in the session? Which contains the users password in cleartext? That is - at least in my opinion - extremely insecure.

I'd see for a way to not beed the password for subsequent calls but as I don't know your exact environment I'm out on that. Next thing would be to see to store only the encrypted password and decrypt it when needed. But not dtoring at all would be prefered!

Have you had a look at the sourcecode of f.e. Gosa or PHPLdapAdmin? They had a similar problem to solve.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. I have implemented it with include now.